# MongoDb Volume alert so much iops(>10000)

Tags: mongodb

I am new for MongoDB. I have setup mongodb for my production server.

I have setup alert in aws ec2 instance for iops and it gives me alert every 15 minutes that iops reached at > 10000.

I am not able to figure out the issue.

I ran mongostat, iostat but these are not showing me any critical issue for ops.

Please help me I am so worried from this issue.

Thanks in advance,

Vijay

Comment: what else is running there? can you share the ec2 characteristics?

Comment: Which type of ec2 characteristics? What command I run for getting ec2 characteristics? the ec2 intance I use here is singapore large with two EBS volumes for mongodb and mongodb logs as GENERAL PURPOSE(SSD).

Comment: Hi Antonis Can we chat live for this issue? My skype id is barnwal8 please send me request for chat, Iam so worry about this issue.